# Months go into a crystal reports Cross-Tab column

Tags: crystal-reports-2016

```
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 02, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 02, 28, 23, 59, 00) then "FEB" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 03, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 03, 31, 23, 59, 00) then "MAR" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 04, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 04, 30, 23, 59, 00) then "APR" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 05, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 05, 31, 23, 59, 00) then "MAY" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 06, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 06, 30, 23, 59, 00) then "JUN" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 07, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 07, 31, 23, 59, 00) then "JUL" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 08, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 08, 31, 23, 59, 00) then "AUG" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 09, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 09, 30, 23, 59, 00) then "SEP" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 10, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 10, 31, 23, 59, 00) then "OCT" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 11, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 11, 30, 23, 59, 00) then "NOV" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2019, 12, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2019, 12, 31, 23, 59, 00) then "DEC" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2020, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2020, 01, 31, 23, 59, 00) then "JAN'20" else
if {workorder.targcompdate} in DateTime (2020, 02, 01, 00, 00, 00) to DateTime (2020, 02, 29, 23, 59, 00) then "FEB'20"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ucase(ToText({workorder.targcompdate}, "MMM yy"))

Comment: Or
Replace(Ucase(ToText({workorder.targcompdate}, "MMM yy"))," ","'")